# No puedo usar la tecla especifica que coloco en c++ en cin.getlink (variable, espacio, tecla para saltar)

Tags: c++

Hola a todos cordial saludo, ultimamente estaba usando c++ para probar distintas cosas y en el codigo no me deja usar el tipo de letra que coloco en

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char Desz[10];
    
    cout << "Digite una descripcion del zapato..."<< endl << "\n";
    cin.getline(Desz, 10, 'a');
    
    cout << Desz;
}
```

`cin.getlink` para poder continuar con el programa y solo cuando digito los caracteres solo sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que quiero es que me muestre para poder presionar una tecla para poder seguir con el código.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Algun experto te va a orientar mejor.. pero para empezar, tu cadena solo puede aceptar hasta 10 caracteres... por eso te sale cortado..

Comment: vos le decis que lea hasta la a.. y es lo que esta haciendo.. que querias que hiciera?

Comment: El programa hace lo esperado, que es lo que tu querias que hiciera? Creo que falta que detalles un poco mas eso.

Comment: ahh ok yo pensaba que lo que tenia que hacer era que al presionar la tecla a el prograna siguiera su curso.